# scalebox vertical alignment

Tags: symbols

How can I adjust the height of the red symbol?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{1}{$\neq$}
\scalebox{1.4}{$\neq$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\raisebox` is the generic command for raising or lowering boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{1}{$\neq$}%
\raisebox{-1pt}{\scalebox{1.4}{$\neq$}}
\end{document}
```